# Script that goes through files in a directory AND subdirectories

Tags: bash

I have a simple problem to which I don't find the answer on the net.

Like the title states it, I would like to go trough all the files in a directory AND his sub-directories. I know how to do it with `find` command but I would like to know how to do it with a simple `for` loop.

I initially have this line :

```
for file in $dir/*.png; do
```

And I'm sure there is a way to have some kind of `$dir/*/*.png` line that makes it possible with a `for` loop.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Hi, is there any specific reason to avoid using the find command? It makes life easier to use any decent tools available.

Comment: if only you could ``find`` an answer

Comment: just a `for` loop won't help you (you don't know levels of directory hierarchy). Without `find` tool, you may try to go with a recursive function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for file in $(find $dir - type f - name "*.png"); do

Comment: Thanks, I suppose there is no choice but to use that `find` command.